# Configure Same DNS Zone to multiple cloud providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, dns, cloud, devops

Is it possible to configure same dns zone to multiple cloud ?

I have example.com configured at AWS route 53 all the services created under aws are easily configurable as name1.example.com, name2.example.com automated.

Now i have few services running on Google cloud and would want to automate the DNS creation for GCP as well ex: name3.example.com (currently manually updating the record in aws route53)

Services using:
Kubernetes and external DNS

Comment: "Is it possible to configure same dns zone to multiple cloud ?" Yes, and that is the easy part, even if your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. The difficult part is the delegation from the parent: it needs to list ALL nameservers so the union of the multiple DNS providers you use. And in most cases it means cooperation between those providers, you can not just mix and match some and hope it will work. In short this is advanced design, don't do it if you don't master DNS already, and obviously consult each DNS provider for advices.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy externa-dns on GKE and configure it to update your route 53 records.